# How can I add two different integer fields of the same model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Score(models.Model):
  Score_A=models.IntegerField()
  Score_B=models.IntegerField()
```

How can I put the sum of these two fields into another field?

Comment: Do you want this to happen automatically or what's the problem with just adding them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the save method so when a record is created or updated the value of the sum will be saved like below

```
class Score(models.Model):
  Score_A=models.IntegerField()
  Score_B=models.IntegerField()
  sum=models.IntegerField()
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sum = self.Score_A +self.Score_B
        super(Score, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions for this create a trigger in a database that stores a total of the two fields in another field.

Answer (score 0):

I would really advise *not* to store the sum of the two fields, but simply annotate the queryset. That way you avoid *data duplication*, which will make the database slightly larger, but more important, it will be quite hard to keep the fields in sync.

```
from django.db.models import F

Score.objects.annotate(Score_total=F('Score_A')+F('Score_B'))
```

the `Score` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `Score_total`, which is the sum of the two fields.

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `score_a` instead of <s>`Score_A`</s>.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the solutions people presented is that they work with the database, This adds some overhead, You want to do something like this

```
class Score(models.Model):
    Score_A = models.IntegerField()
    Score_B = models.IntegerField()

    def overall_score(self):
        return self.Score_A + self.Score_B
```

This won't alter the database, This may have some side effects like *RACE CODITIONS*, Be sure to use `select_for_update` or whatever way you prefer to lock the `DB` when using the `Score` model.

I'd like to mention that you should stick with pep8, `score_a`, `score_b`